# asp.net WEB API with database connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to ASP.NET WEB API. I'm trying to create APIs that have connections to a database. For example like login method or add data to a database. But when I tried to search for example tutorial, I couldn't find an example which has a connection string inside it.

My questions are :

1. How do I set my connection string to my database? (i.e. user name and password)
2. Can I connect to a database which is not in my localhost? (i.e. another server)

If anyone could explain to me about ASP.NET WEB API that has a connection with database, I would really appreciate it.

**Im using visual studio 2012 right now. the database that I would use is MSSQL.

Thx

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2b481f/retrieve-data-from-database-in-Asp-Net-web-api/

Comment: the official samples from Microsoft cover this in depth. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28413289/1257607) may help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. how do i set my connection string to my database? for example my username and password? :** Its better put your connections string in the webconfig, so you can change it when you need [How to: Read Connection Strings from the Web.config File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx)

**2. Can i connect to a database which is not in my localhost (for example in another server):** Of course, but first, you need to choose what technology use to access database, you can use Entity Framework, Classic ADO.NET, NHibernate, for example with Entity Framework read: [Entity Framework (EF) Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907), also read: [Using Web API 2 with Entity Framework 6](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-1)